# parsing xml array not displaying all data in view

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Im trying to display Ebay GetSingleItem response (http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/GetSingleItem.html) and Im having problems displaying array ["ItemSpecifics"]. The call is working ok and I´m receiving the following information:

```
["ItemSpecifics"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListArrayType)#208 (2) {
          ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(1) {
            ["NameValueList"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#129 (5) {
              ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(8) {
                [0] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType)#207 (2) {
                  ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["Name"] => string(6) "Format"
                    ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#191 (5) {
                      ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                        [0] => string(10) "DVD/HD-DVD"
                      }
                      ["position":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => int(0)
                      ["class":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(44) "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType"
                      ["property":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(5) "Value"
                      ["expectedType":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(6) "string"
                    }
                  }
                  ["attachment":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["data"] => NULL
                    ["mimeType"] => NULL
                  }
                }
                [1] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType)#65 (2) {
                  ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["Name"] => string(5) "Genre"
                    ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#152 (5) {
                      ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                        [0] => string(16) "Sci-Fi & Fantasy"
                      }
                      ["position":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => int(0)
                      ["class":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(44) "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType"
                      ["property":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(5) "Value"
                      ["expectedType":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(6) "string"
                    }
                  }
                  ["attachment":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["data"] => NULL
                    ["mimeType"] => NULL
                  }
                }
                [2] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType)#180 (2) {
                  ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["Name"] => string(7) "Edition"
                    ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#253 (5) {
                      ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                        [0] => string(10) "Widescreen"
                      }
                      ["position":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => int(0)
                      ["class":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(44) "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType"
                      ["property":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(5) "Value"
                      ["expectedType":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(6) "string"
                    }
```

So in my controller I put the following information:

```
$event = array();
            foreach($item->ItemSpecifics->NameValueList as $data){
                $event[] = $data;
            }
```

I set the data using:                     `->setCollection($event)`

and in my html page (view) I used:

```
<?php $res = $this->getCollection() ?>
<?php foreach ($res as $row)
{
    echo "<tr id='0' class='0'>
                    <td>
                        <div class='name'>" . $row->Name . " </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class='value'>" . $row->Value . " </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>";
} ?>
```

but my problem is that the data included in NAME only is retrieved. the information in Value is not retrieved into the view. just to put more in clear with an example. The information = FORMAT is displayed but DVD/HD-DVD is not.

```
["Name"] => string(6) "Format"
                        ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#191 (5) {
                          ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                            [0] => string(10) "DVD/HD-DVD"
                          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->Value` is an object, and the `->Value->data` property is marked as private. That means you cannot read it from outside (without doing reflection) but instead need to call a relevant method to read its value. Looking at the implementation of UnboundType we see that you should be able to read the ->Value object as if it was an array (they implement the ArrayAccess interface). The data you want is in position 0 so try this:

```
$row->Value[0]
```